# Firebase demora na primeira busca no banco de dados

Tags: firebase

Olá tenho um app de pedidos e tals ele tem login cadastro de tudo... Porem eu percebi que quando fazer a primeira busca de algum dado dentro do aplicativo o tempo de resposta e alto e na segunda vez flui muito bem. Para mim isto não incomoda porem para o usuário seria algo ruim. Teria como arrumar isto ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há uma sobrecarga ao estabelecer uma conexão pela primeira vez. A conexão é sobre um websocket seguro, e para garantir que ele seja seguro, há várias viagens de ida e volta entre o cliente e o servidor necessário.

O que voce pode fazer é a acessar o Firebase assim que o aplicativo for iniciado, em vez de esperar pela primeira vez (quando você faz sua primeira requisição). Isso iniciará a conexão do websocket o mais rápido possível, então o atraso percebido da primeira solicitação de dados reais não será tão dolorosa.

Já fizemos algo parecido mas era com outras tecnologias, nós chamávamos de "Database Warmup"

Comment: obrigado pela dica!!!